# Sql query that outputs to ONE Joptionpane

Tags: java, sql, joptionpane

String sql = "SELECT TOP 10 id, Trailer, Block, Location, Day, SetTime, Comment FROM TrailerLocation" 
                      + " ORDER BY id DESC";

```
   rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

   while(rs.next()){
        //Retrieve by column name
            int id  = rs.getInt("id");
        String trailer = rs.getString("Trailer");
        String block = rs.getString("Block");
        String location = rs.getString("Location");
        String date = rs.getString("Day");
        String comment = rs.getString("Comment");

        //Display values
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
              "ID: " + id
            + ", Trailer: " + trailer 
            + ", Block: " + block 
            + ", Location: " + location 
            + ", Date & Time: " + date 
            + ", Comment: " + comment);


    }
```

I want the Joptionpane to only display once with all the data not ten times.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with any sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ... ) after the while loop.
And, in the while loop, add the informations you want in one unique string which you will display in you JOptionPane.

```
rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
while(rs.next()){

    //Retrieve by column name

    str.append("ID: " + rs.getInt("id"));
    str.append(", Trailer: " + rs.getString("Trailer"));
    str.append(", Block: " + rs.getString("Block"));
    str.append(", Location: " + rs.getString("Location"));
    str.append(", Date: " + rs.getString("Day"));
    str.append(", Comment: " + rs.getString("Comment"));

    //new line
    str.append("\n");
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,str.toString());
```